# In tkinter entry widget, failed to type in Indian language using sanskrit/hindi keyboard

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, unicode, utf-8, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

lst = ['रामायणसारः', 'देवयाज्ञिकपद्धतिः', 'तर्कसङ्ग्रहः',]


def check_input(event):
    value = event.widget.get()

    if value == '':
        data = lst
    else:
        data = []
        for item in lst:
            if value.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)
    update(data)


def update(data):
    # Clear the Combobox
    menu.delete(0, END)
    # Add values to the combobox
    for value in data:
        menu.insert(END, value)


def fillout(event):
    combo_box.delete(0, END)
    combo_box.insert(0, menu.get(menu.curselection()))


combo_box = Entry(root, width=10, font=("Times", 12))
combo_box.place(relx=0.20, rely=0.4, relwidth=0.45, relheight=0.1)
combo_box.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_input)


menu = Listbox(root)
menu.place(relx=0.20, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.45, relheight=0.1)
menu.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", fillout)

update(lst)
```

while typing Indian language(Sanskrit/Hindi) text in entry box using sanskrit/hindi keyboard, it shows question mark, please help to rectify the issue.

[ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWyNw.png)

I have also tried encoding('utf-8') with entry widget, but it doesn't worked.

Comment: Do you have the problem only with keyboard? I can copy Sanskrit to an Entry box and it shows correctly. So I don't seem do be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, if we are copying the sanskrit/hindi text, it works fine. But, otherwise if we are typing it through keyboard question mark comes in place of text. Input needs to be taken through user, and thus it is required through keyboard available on windows.

Comment: What do I do in combo_box if I typed ?12help?

Comment: @toyotaSupra Hi, type anything through sanskrit/hindi keyboard, and it will display question mark and not the typed words. For eg. type रामा through keyboard and not copy paste the same, and problem will get reproduce